# return value only if Observer method called

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to achieve to return value of method only if Observer method called. But didn't know the right way. I use let but it's required unit and i have to return `MutableList<Pair<String,String>>`.

That's my method:

```
 override fun getPlaylistsNameAndId(userCategory: String):MutableList<Pair<String,String>> {
    val abc = mutableListOf<Pair<String,String>>()
        addPlaylistViewModel.getPlaylistsForChips(userCategory).observe(this, Observer { it ->
            it.forEach {
                abc.add(Pair(it.playlistName,it.playlistId))
            }
            //i'm called
        })
   // return if (observer called) else wait for calling.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that observe is an async operation. So your method will return immediately after setting up the observer. The observer will only execute later - asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in my application: (Pseudo code)

```
val myData: List<MyData> = arrayListOf()
val myLiveData: LiveData<List<MyData>> by lazy { MyRoomDatabase.getInstance(this).myDataDao().myDataLive }

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    myLiveData.observe(this, Observer { data ->
        myData = data
    }
}
```

Essentially, whenever the live data updates, it'll also update the `myData` property.
So any time we access the `myData` property, it should be up to date.

Comment: thank you for answer, i'm actually have less concern for liveData and more for returning value if observer method called as described in answer.